# Get all the rows where a certain column does not repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Color (
    id int,
    name varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO
    Color
VALUES
    (1,  'Blue'),
    (2,   'Red'),
    (3, 'Black'),
    (4, 'Black'),
    (5, 'White'),
    (6, 'White');
```

I need a query to show only the rows where the color does not repeat in any other row.

Expected result table:

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue |
| 2 | Red |

I tried selecting the desired result table doing this:

```
Select c3.id, c2.name
FROM (
    SELECT name, count(*)
        FROM color c1
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING count(*) = 1
    ) c2 INNER JOIN color c3 on c3.name = c2.name
```

Comment: Your attempt is pretty much what you have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`

```
select id, name
from Color C1
where not exists (select 1 from Color C2 where C2.name = C1.name and C2.id <> C1.id);
```

Comment: @TomuRain did this perform better than the other options? Or just look neater? :)

Comment: I would also be interested in the answer to that question. While I can see this answer possibly bring the most readable (and it would certainly provide a correct result), I rarely find "not exists" to be the best performing.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(id) as id, name 
FROM color
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(id)=1
```

@TomuRain was on the right track with the subquery using "having" to limit the results to only those records with a count of 1. In fact, the query that was posted in the question works. I believe that the question being asked was if there was a cleaner way (I'm guessing without the use of a subquery) to get to the same result. If you think about it, the question you are really wanting to ask with your query is "Which colors only have one ID associated with them?" That's why "having count(id)=1" makes sense, as well as why you would group by name. However, the rules of the sql language require that when you use a "group by", that each column of the query be included in the group by, or be an aggregate. Including id in the group by would not get the results you are looking for. However, since we have limited our results to colors with a single ID, several aggregates will work, because aggregating a single record will return the value of that record, including MAX, MIN, or even SUM. I chose to use MAX.

Comment: @JeremyCaney, I find it interesting that I was asked to explain my code (which I have now done). While it may not be as readable and easy to understand as the "not exists" answer, it is certainly clearer than the "window functions"  answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use window function

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
    FROM Color c
)
WHERE count = 1;
```

Alternatively, and probably more performant:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      nextId = LEAD(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id),
      prevId =  LAG(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)
    FROM Color c
)
WHERE nextId IS NULL AND prevId IS NULL;
```